# How to select records from DB in Laravel that are within the range of days of each month

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have table with records. In table i have column **'payment_date'**, and it's **integer with unix timestamp**. I need to select records from the database that are in the time interval of two days for each year and each month.[image].

For example - I need all records from **1** to **15**. This means that the result should contain entries for each year and each month from the 1st to the 15th:

```
from 2022-01-01 - to 2022-01-15
from 2022-02-01 - to 2022-02-15
//////////////////////
from 2023-07-01 - to 2023-07-15 etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$query->whereRaw('DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date))  BETWEEN ' . $from . ' AND ' . $to);

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve records for each year and each month from the 1st to the 15th, you can use a combination of date functions like this:

> SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date) BETWEEN
> DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date), '%Y-%m-01') AND
> DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(payment_date), '%Y-%m-01'),
> INTERVAL 14 DAY);